# Insert hash values into another hash in ruby without outer parentesis

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following data structure in one of my templates:

```
[
  {
    geometry: {
      type: geometry, coordinates: coordinates
    },
  }
]
```

and then i have an options-hash that looks like this:

```
options = { label: "Hot Chicken Takeover",
            tooltip: "5 stars",
            color: "#0090ff" }
```

how can i add the key-value pairs from options into the array above so that it looks like this:

```
[
  {
    geometry: {
      type: geometry, coordinates: coordinates
    },
    label: "Hot Chicken Takeover",
    tooltip: "5 stars",
    color: "#0090ff"
  }
]
```

is there any way to "flatten" a hash in ruby?

Comment: You can write `a.first.update options`, thought this mutates `a`, your given array (`[{:geometry....`). Note that `geometry` and `coordinates` are undefined variables or methods.

Comment: This is no "flattening" here, you're just merging one hash into another. The fact that the destination hash is inside an array seems unrelated to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the given below example, we first access the first element of the data array using `data[0]`. We then merge the `options` hash into the `geometry` hash using `merge` method. The resulting hash is assigned back to data[0].

```
data = [{ geometry: { type: 'geometry', coordinates: [1, 2] }}]

options = { label: "Hot Chicken Takeover",
            tooltip: "5 stars",
            color: "#0090ff" }

data[0] = data[0].merge(options)

puts data.inspect
```

output

```
[{:geometry=>{:type=>"geometry", :coordinates=>[1, 2]}, :label=>"Hot Chicken Takeover", :tooltip=>"5 stars", :color=>"#0090ff"}]
```